# How to partially mock 'equalsIgnoreCase' method of java.lang.String

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock

I am using Mockito/Power Mockito for unit testing.
I want to mock the method 'equalsIgnoreCase' in  java.lang.String class.

Other methods of java.lang.String should behave as it is, I want to mock only 'equalsIgnoreCase' method.

Could anyone please give an example for this ?

Comment: Why would you want to do a thing like this?

Comment: I don't think you can mock a final class, which java.lang.String is...

Comment: I have a situation where equalsIgnoreCase defines a loop condition.

Something like 

while(str1.equalsIgnoreCase(str2)){
...
}

I do not have a control over str1 and str2. They get initialized/modified dynamically during the execution of the method.
Hence I would want to mock the équalsIgnoreCase' method and return true so that control flows into the loop

Comment: It seems that you're going to far too low a level.  What is the contract of this method that you're testing?  What cases is it intended to cover?  Try writing a test that doesn't care about str1, str2 and equalsIgnoreCase; but instead focuses on whatever the method is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

Rewrite your `while` condition so that it calls a method. This benefits you in several ways:

1. It's easy to mock
2. It won't throw an exception if `str1` is null.
3. It documents exactly what the loop is trying to accomplish.